# 'Unable to identify browser type' message displayed while using Internet explorer 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have written a java code to update a software and see the update status.
I have written the code in eclipse and I want update the software using a GUI.
In GUI there is a link clicking which we can see update status. Internet Explorer 11 is the default browser.But when that link is clicked an error message named

" Unable to identify browser type"message is displayed.

This is my java code:

```
    protected static void retrieveIAInfo() {

    String appString = readDefaultBrowserCommand();

    // XTSce63590: manage Mozilla and Firefox 

    // commandline in the registry

    if (isIE(appString)) {

    m_DefaultBrowserPath = extractIECmd(appString);

    } else if (isMozilla(appString)) {

    m_DefaultBrowserPath = extractMozillaCmd(appString);

    } else if (isFireFox(appString)) {

    m_DefaultBrowserPath = extractMozillaCmd(appString);          

    } else {

    throw new RegistryUtilitiesException("Unable to identify browser     

    type.",RegistryUtilitiesException.NO_BROWSER);

    }

    if (m_DefaultBrowserPath== null) {

    throw new RegistryUtilitiesException("Unable to identify brwoser     

    type.",RegistryUtilitiesException.NO_BROWSER);        

    }

    System.out.println("IABrowserPath: " + m_DefaultBrowserPath);

    }

    protected static String extractIECmd(String cmd) {

    String browser_cmd = null;

    //int index = cmd.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf ("-nohome");

    int index = cmd.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf ("-url");

    if (index != -1) {

    cmd = cmd.substring(0, index);

    // if (cmd.charAt(0) == '"') {

    //  index = cmd.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf ("\"");

    if (cmd.charAt(0) == '"') {

    index = cmd.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf ("%1"); 

    if (index != -1) {

    browser_cmd = cmd.substring(1, index);

    }

    }

    }

    return browser_cmd;

    }
```

In the function retrieveIAInfo, when extractIECmd(appString) is called the function is always returning false. Therefore the throw command 
"Unable to identify browser type"
in retrieveIAInfo is getting executed.
In the case of other browsers like Mozilla no problem is there.Only in the case of Iinternet Explorer 11 browser the exception is throwing.

The cmd is extracting the index from the following register value:

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"%1

Can somebody help me to take the value of %1 as lastIndexOf variable in the function extractIECmd

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned that the browsers other than Internet explorer 11 are all working fine.
To solve this problem we have to extract the register value of Internet explorer 11
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\"%1"

eliminate %1 and get C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

This can be done by changing the 'extractIECmd()' function as

protected static String extractIECmd(String qq) {

```
  String browser_cmd = "";

  *int index = qq.toString().lastIndexOf ("");*
  if (index != -1) {
      qq = qq.substring(0, index);

     if (qq.charAt(0) == '"') {
         index = qq.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf ("\""); 
          if (index != -1) {
              browser_cmd = qq.substring(1, index);


          }
      }
  }
  return browser_cmd;
```

}

Now Internet Explorer also working fine
The problem is solved